# Using cypress, I want to get the number of matched interfaces in the code and number of responses which matched this route

Tags: javascript, cypress

Like descripted in following image，how can I get the number of responses which matched this route, and log it in my code?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCwL0.png)

My code looks like this, if I print xhr in a loop, an error occurs

```
a.forEach(function(item) {
            cy.server()
            cy.route({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '**',
            }).as(item)

            cy.visit(item)
            a = '@' + item
            cy.wait(a).then((xhr) => {
                // cy.log( item);
                cy.log( xhr.url);
            });
            cy.wait(1000)

            var i = 0
            for (;i < 3;i++){
                    cy.wait('@gets').then((xhr) => {
                        cy.log( xhr.url);
                        // cy.log(JSON.stringify(xhr.response.body));
                    });
                }

        })
```

Comment: Can you add the error that occurs?

Comment: For example, there are 3 matching interfaces. When I try to get the fourth one, it will cause the waiting timeout 5000ms. I just want to get the number of matches, but I don't know what method to use. thank you